# How can I return all rows for a value where at least one row meets a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to return all rows for IDs where one or more Num_Occurrence rows is >=10.

Here is an example of the raw data:

```
+------+-----------+----------------+
| ID   | YearMonth | Num_Occurrence |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201601    | 7              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201602    | 8              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201603    | 12             |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201604    | 9              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 9898 | 201601    | 9              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 9898 | 201602    | 8              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 9898 | 201603    | 9              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 9898 | 201604    | 6              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
```

And here is the desired output:

```
+------+-----------+----------------+
| ID   | YearMonth | Num_Occurrence |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201601    | 7              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201602    | 8              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201603    | 12             |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201604    | 9              |
+------+-----------+----------------+
```

I understand that the following will not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Num_Occurrence >= 10
```

Because that would only return this row:

```
+------+-----------+----------------+
| ID   | YearMonth | Num_Occurrence |
+------+-----------+----------------+
| 1234 | 201603    | 12             |
+------+-----------+----------------+
```

As aforementioned, I need to return ALL rows for that ANY ID where Num_Occurrence is >=10.

Thanks!!

Comment: You may want to use EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl] t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tbl] t2
              WHERE t2.ID = t1.id
              AND t2.Num_Occurrence >= 10);
```

The "EXISTS" clause here uses a sub-query to find all rows having Num_Occurrence >= 10, then compares that against the complete table to get all rows with a matching ID.

Comment: Why would you write same answer as @Gordon. And he wrote his answer 30 min before you.

Comment: (and I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, so providing a correct answer seemed the logical way to go)

Comment: @CoderofCode: `t2.Num_Occurrence >= 10` is correct, `t2.id >= 10` is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where exists (select 1
              from tbl t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.id >= 10
             );
```